# how to install Neo 4j in ubuntu

Tags: server, database, neo4j

How to install neo4j in Ubuntu server by command line. I really didn't found any good documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add repository to the list of sources:

```
wget -O - https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo 'deb https://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neo4j.list
sudo apt-get update
```

To install the latest Neo4j Community Edition:

```
sudo apt-get install neo4j
```

To install the latest Neo4j Enterprise Edition:

```
sudo apt-get install neo4j-enterprise
```

Make sure java 8 or above is installed in your system.